# Search for a substring and enter a new line

Tags: bash, sed, awk, newline

I am looking to search through a file using awk or sed and when it comes across a particular letter/substring it inserts a new line before it. An example of my file below:

```
"ABC" "3 0 1 0 1" "ABC" "0 2 0 2 0"
```

So when it finds the string ABC it inserts a new line so the output looks like this:

```
"ABC" "3 0 1 0 1"
"ABC" "0 2 0 2 0"
```

Then once it has completed this step I would like to sum the values together giving an output like this:

```
"ABC" "3 0 1 0 1" "5"
"ABC" "0 2 0 2 0" "4"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `GNU awk` then this will do the trick:

```
BEGIN {
    FPAT="\"[^\"]+\""                    # Describe the field pattern
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {               # Loop over all the fields
        n=split($(i+1),x,/[\" ]/)        # Split the numbers fields
        s = 0                            # Variable for the sum of number field
        for (j=2;j<n;j++) {              # Loop over each number in field
            s += x[j]                    # Summation
        }
        print $i,$(i+1),"\""s"\""        # Print field pairs and sum
    }
}
```

Save it to a file such as `script.awk` and run like:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
"ABC" "3 0 1 0 1" "5"
"ABC" "0 2 0 2 0" "4"
```

Comment: IF I don't have gnu awk? ANy other solutions?

Comment: What system are you running?

Comment: I tried your example but it doesn't appear to work I may have more than 5 numbers in a line I could have anything up to 100

Comment: That is not a problem with my script I handle a dynamic number of numbers. Do you have GNU awk or not!?!?

Comment: I'm not sure how can I check?

Comment: I have gnu awk installed

Comment: If you have `GNU awk` then means the example file you posted is not representative of your actual file. Does the file really contain the double quotes around the fields?

Comment: It does I can export the file in several different ways, for this example I exported to tsv but I can export to csv also

Comment: That doesn't really help, the script I posted does exactly what was asked in the question. Your file must be different in some way and without posting the actual file their isn't much I can do.

Comment: Since the OP is talking about exporting to tsv or csv, I suspect he probably has his data in Excel or some other Windows tool and so MS are polluting his data with control-Ms when he exports it. Try running dos2unix on the exported file before running the awk script on it.

Comment: @EdMorton this is my main suspicion also.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in 2 passes for simplicity:

```
$ cat file
"ABC" "3 0 1 0 1" "ABC" "0 2 0 2 0"

$ awk -v t='"ABC"' '{gsub(" *"t,"\n"t)}1' file |
    awk -F\" 'NF{split($4,a,/ /); s=0; for (i in a) s+=a[i]; print $0, FS s FS}'
"ABC" "3 0 1 0 1" "5"
"ABC" "0 2 0 2 0" "4"
```

Comment: Surprising solution from you Ed, I didn't think piping `awk` into `awk` would be your thing.

Comment: Yeah, and I ALMOST had piping sed into awk but couldn't quite pull the trigger :-). It's just so much simpler to separate the input into records first when there clearly are records but no specific record separator in the original file. The purist in me wanted to do a solution all in one awk call, but realistically this is the way I'd actually do it.